# Why does Ubuntu write to disk when copying files from CD to USB?

Tags: 14.04, usb, xubuntu, disk, cd

My machine has 18GB of main memory. When copying files from a mounted CD to a mounted USB drive there is a lot of HDD activity.

Why does Ubuntu write to disk when copying from CD to USB? I assume there is some sort of buffering or caching going on but should the main memory not be sufficient to cache all the files, especially since it is larger than both the CD and the USB drive?